# datagridview color is not changing through validation

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

```
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[1];
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

This code does not change the color if we apply in C#.net.  let me know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: this answer is working, but i wanted for some specific rows to color. means make a condition if satisfied make that row as green or else red. thanks in advance

Comment: can you plz mark the answer like a good answer or rate it ,if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You change the DefaultCellStyle.BackColor instead of the Style.BackColor which is the one actually used in the Paint event of the cells.

Changing your code to change the Style.BackColor of each cell in the row should do the trick.

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
  cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

You can find more information on how the DefaultCellStyle is used [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4sab6f9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

Comment: My bad. The Style property is of the cell itself. The row only has the DefaultCellStyle. Try iterating through the cells of the row and set the Style.Background.